# updating one to many relationship automatically

Tags: php, laravel

I have two tables(notification and alertFrequency) with their respective `models`. There is a one-to-many relationship. It works. when i try to update it automatically, here is where I get the issues. In short my model notification is:

```
class Notification extends Model
{
    public function alertFrequencies()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\AlertFrequency');
    }

    public function alert()
    {
        $alert_frequency = AlertFrequency::with('notification')
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->select('created_at')->first();
        if ($alert_frequency == null) {
            return false;
        }
        return $alert_frequency->created_at->toDateTimeString();
    }
}
```

It returns time stamp.

What I'am trying to accomplish in the guzzle controller is to update the `created_at`(field in `alertFrequency` table) with `notification_id`(field in `alertFrequency` table). the code is as follows

```
public function status()
{
    $notifications = Notification::where('active', 1)->get();
    $status = Status::where('name', 'health')->first();
    foreach ($notifications as $notification) {
        $this->updateStatus($notification, $status);
    }
}

private function updateStatus(Notification $notification, Status $status, AlertFrequency $alert)
{
    $status_health = $notification->status('health');
    $check = empty($status_health['timestamp']);
    $elapsed_time = $check ? 10000 : \Carbon\Carbon::parse($status_health['timestamp'])->diffInMinutes();
    $check_frequency = $this->getCheckFrequency($notification);
    if ($check || $elapsed_time >= $check_frequency) {
        $resCode = $this->getStatusCode($notification->website_url);
        $this->addStatusToNotification($notification, $status, $resCode);
        $this->sendNotification(
            $notification,
            $status_health,
            $this->getAlertFrequency($alert),
            $resCode
        );
        /*working right for alert*/
        var_dump($this->getAlertFrequency);
    }
}

private function getAlertFrequency(AlertFrequency $notification)
{
    if ($notification->alert() == null) {
        return false;
    }
    return $notification->alert();
}
```

till function update, I am able to `var_dump()` the value and is working correctly. but I don't know how to call it in the `status` function so that it will automatically update the `alerFrequency` table? would appreciate your help!

Comment: What is the structure of `alerFrequency` table

Comment: it is a simple model with a belongs to many relationship::::public function notification(){
     return $this->belongsTo('App\Notification');
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to call `updateStatus()` method from `status()`. You cannot do it as `updateStatus()` expect instance of `AlertFrequency` as an argument. This is the issue.

If so, slightly change your ``updateStatus() method like this so you don't need to pass `AlertFrequency` as an argument. You can resolve it using `app()` method inside `updateStatus()` method.

With you comment I've made some changes.

```
private function updateStatus(Notification $notification, Status $status)
{
     $alert = app(AlertFrequency::class);
    // Rest of your code here

    if ($check || $elapsed_time >= $check_frequency) {
        return $this->getAlertFrequency();
    }
    return null;
}

public function status()
{
    $notifications = Notification::where('active', 1)->get();
    $status = Status::where('name', 'health')->first();
    foreach ($notifications as $notification) {
        $frequency = $this->updateStatus($notification, $status);
        if (!empty($frequency)) {
            $notification->alertFrequencies()->create([
                'notification_id' => $frequency
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

> Before using the create method, be sure to review the documentation on [attribute mass assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#mass-assignment).

Comment: u r right but, if you get my question clearly, the situation is like this:  the status function updates the notification, status and alerFrequncy tables in the database. notification and alertFrequency have one to many relationship. i should be able to get the alerfrequency table anyways.

Comment: ur answer gave me a different insight that is why i changed the alerFrequency and add some class! tnx